# Алгоритм упорядочивания символов в строке java?

Tags: java, алгоритм

**Есть строка:**
в java:

`String MyString = "|0|17|19|20|17|0|";`

**Вопрос:** как вывести на экран (в консоль) строку в другом формате
,а именно, должно все быть по порядку проиндексировано
,а именно,

`MyString = "0|1|2|3|1|0";`

Если число в строке впервые встречается то нужно его записать как 0, а дальше, по порядку нумерации (ряда натуральных чисел).
Не минусуйте, я только что вышел из минуса, просто дайте совет, как реализовать это, может быть я не знаю точное название проблемы, и т.п. и т.д.

```
package j;
public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
      String MyString = "|0|17|19|20|17|0|";
 <Помощь зала знатоков>
 <Помощь зала знатоков>
 <Помощь зала знатоков>
 <Помощь зала знатоков>
 <Помощь зала знатоков>
      System.out.println(MyString+"");
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот что получилось, то мне и нужно, спасибо @tym32167 и @Кирилл Малышев;

**Дано:** `0/17/19/20/17/0/22/255/20`
**Вывод:** `0/1/2/3/1/0/4/5/3`

```
package j;
public class J1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
mySort0( "0/17/19/20/17/0/22/255/20", "/");
}
public static void mySort0(String MyWord, String MyDelimiter){
    String de=MyDelimiter;
    String myString = MyWord;
    int[] indexes = new int[256];
    for (int i =0; i < indexes.length; i++) indexes[i] = -1;

    String res = "";
    int current = 0;

    String s[] = myString.split(de);
      for(int i=0;i<=s.length-1;i++){  

        int value = Integer.parseInt(s[i]);
        int index = indexes[value];

        if (index < 0) {
            index = current;
            indexes[value] = current;
            current++;
        }
        //res = res + de + index;
        
        if("".equals(res)){res=index+"";} 
        else {res = res+ de+ index;}
            
        
    }  
      System.out.println("MyInputWord: "+MyWord);
      System.out.println("MyOutWord:" +res);}


}
```

Comment: Ребят, а если ограничиться не байтом, а слово будет скажем 100MB, можно будет проверять этим же макаром?Иными словами, как проверить текст весом 100MB данным методом?

Answer (score 2):

```
String myString = "|0|17|19|20|17|0|";
Map<String, Integer> rankMap = new HashMap<>();
int maxRank = 0;
String res = "";
for (String s : myString.split("\\|")) {
    if (s.isEmpty()) {
        continue;
    }
    int rank;
    if (rankMap.containsKey(s)) {
        rank = rankMap.get(s);
    } else {
        rank = maxRank;
        maxRank++;
        rankMap.put(s, rank);
    }
    res += (res.isEmpty() ? "" : "|") + rank;
}
System.out.println(res);  // 0|1|2|3|1|0
```

Comment: это всё хорошо работает, спасибо, ))) но где достать пошаговый алгоритм, я написал об этом в теме:  чтобы были методы только ```split()``` и ```.equals()```,  без ```Map<String, int>```. Можно сделать этот алгоритм обычным массивом? Заранее, благодарствую.

Comment: @ArthurAlunts числа в строке вашей в каком то диапазоне?

Comment: @tym32167 , `от 0 до 255`; поможете?Например, `"4|6|2|6|22|99|0|11|255|33"` Поднимите мне рейтинг, только что вышел из минуса, теперь, - снова одна и таже проблема: не могу задавать вопросы!

Answer (score 2):

Заменил словарь из соседнего ответа на массив, получилось следующее

```
    String myString = "|0|17|19|20|17|0|";
    int[] indexes = new int[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) indexes[i] = -1;

    String res = "";
    int current = 0;

    for (String s : myString.split("\\|")) {
        if (s.isEmpty()) {
            continue;
        }

        int value = Integer.parseInt(s);
        int index = indexes[value];

        if (index < 0) {
            index = current;
            indexes[value] = current;
            current++;
        }
        
        res += (res.isEmpty() ? "" : "|") + index;
    }
    System.out.println(res);
```

Comment: Всё работает: ```res += (res.isEmpty() ? "" : "|") + index;```* Вопрос_1: *Но мне не понятно, что значит данное лямбда выражение, можете ответить в комментариях или в своем же ответе? Как написать это лямбда в простом но длинном виде(форме)?

Comment: @ArthurAlunts это не лямбда, обычный тернарный оператор.

Comment: `res = res+ "|" + index; `;
Так понятнее, спасибо,

Comment: `for (String s : myString.split("\\|")) {if (s.isEmpty()) { continue;}` А это совсем не понятно, разберемся, уважаемый? Как это упростить?

Comment: @ArthurAlunts зачем это упрощать? Работает и пусть работает

Comment: Я просто буду дорабатывать этот алгоритм, он должен быть максимально понятным, для меня, а так норм, спасибо, Так чем всё таки заменить это: сделать обычный `String[] s1=myString.split("\\|"){ }` ?

Comment: Если взять вот этот текст `"|0|17|19|20|17|0|"` и сделать `.split("\\|")`, то в результирующем массиве первая и последняя строка будет пустая, потому мы их пропускаем в том условии, что в коде. А то, что вы в комментарии написали я не понял.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126162/discussion-between-arthur-alunts-and-tym32167).

Comment: Значения в строке ограничены байтом?

Comment: @MBo [да](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1292498/%d0%90%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d1%83-java/1292596?noredirect=1#comment2278419_1292509)

Comment: @tym32167  Опс, комменты пересмотрел, увидел. Для этого случая отлично подходит. Автор, конечно, зря детали задачи не описал.

Comment: `for (String s : myString.split("\\|")) { if (s.isEmpty()) {continue;}`
Что почитать чтобы понять эту строку, мне нужно её упростить.

Comment: @ArthurAlunts можете начать [отсюда](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)).